# How to input to a function without "

Tags: python, python-2.7

Function definition is here

```
def printme(str):
   """This prints a string passed into this function"""
   print str
```

You can run it like below

```
printme("I'm first call to user defined function!")
```

I want to do that instead

```
printme(I can do it with this the double quote)
```

What should I amend in my function to be able to do this? I tried this but it did not work out

```
def printme(raw_input()):
    """This prints a string passed into this function"""
```

I got this error

```
File "<ipython-input-31-e1326fb445e6>", line 1
  def printme(raw_input()):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible (if I understand your question).

Comment: Hi @IsmailBadawi you understood correctly

Comment: With the quotes it is a string, without it's just garbage code. Without deep changes to the interpreter, you're SOL.

Comment: @AndyK, I didn't  downvote although that may change

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ;)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Part of my learning curve. Call it probably stubbornness but I like to hear it than not ask the question (and if the question is bad, I would have deleted it ) ;) @PadraicCunningham

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bare words / new keywords in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492895/bare-words-new-keywords-in-python)

Comment: Hi @TML not it's not

Comment: @AndyK `printme(I can do it with this the double quote)` is a duplicate of the "Bare words" question; based on the discussion below, it sounds like your question actually had nothing to avoiding the quotes, but was really more about `raw_input()`. Glad you got an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could arguably do:

```
s = raw_input 

def printme(something):
    """ prints a string... """
    print something
```

And then call on your function like:

```
printme(s())
```

Although not sure that really gets what you want (which is not possible to do), although this does prompt you for input each time you call the function in that manner.

[image]

Comment: Hi @david-zemens, many thanks for the workaround. This is one of the reason why I hate asking questions on Python here. The guys are knowledgeable but are conceited with their knowledge. It feels like a witch hunt , each time I'm asking a basic question. Humility, where are thou?

Comment: @AmitGold a definite no or a workaround. Both would have been good.  David's answer fits me but I like your answer as well. +1 for you.

Comment: @AndyK The answer isn't what you described. You described trying to use a string without quotes, and the answer is about asking the user (once the program is run) for the string. Two different things. (Only continuing this discussion because you may have misunderstood the answer)

Comment: @AmitGold sometimes, [the question is not the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and especially when the strictly *correct* answer is "This is not possible", *workaround* solutions may be preferable. It's up to the OP to decide which of several answers best suits his or her specific needs.

Comment: @DavidZemens in this case the answer isn't exactly an answer either. The answer doesn't do what the question was about. The question was about using a string inside the code without quotes, while the answer includes the user typing the string after the program starts running.

Comment: @DavidZemens this is the story of my life. I need to read carefully about  the article you posted

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that in Python, since that won't be a value, but just a couple of undefined variables.

Comment: Part of my learning curve. Call it probably stubbornness but I like to hear it than not ask the question (and if the question is bad, I would have deleted it ) ;) @amitgold

Comment: in 7 minutes. Thanks mate

Comment: @AmitGold that lacks a certain class, frankly

Comment: @jonrsharpe he earns it. I would have done it differently but he is entitled to do so ;)

Comment: This answer would be better without the "why would you want to do it anyways?" comment. If you need clarification, make that a comment to the question. Otherwise it invites a discussion in the comments of this answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley Agreed. Will remove it. :D

Answer (score 2):

- You may try like this:

  ```
  str_val = "I'm first call to user defined function!"
  printme(str_val)
  ```

  You will get the desired output.
- Using raw_input(), same way, assign it to a variable as:

  ```
  another_str_val = raw_input()
  printme(another_str_val)
  ```

Specifically within the function:

```
    def printme()
        str_val = raw_input()
        print str_val

    printme()
```

Hope this solves your issue.

P.S: Strings are always enclosed in quotes. FYI [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal)

Comment: Hi @rkatkam I want specificly within a function

Comment: The third approach here is nice.

Comment: Hi @rkatkam I like your solution very much. Many thanks for being humble enough to have written an answer. Kudos.